Why does glibc 2.40 give a make check error on #27~22.04.1-Ubuntu?
I am trying to compile glibc 2.40 in Ubuntu 22.04.
make check shows error:
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40/iconv'
Generating locale C.UTF-8: this might take a while...
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Charmap: "UTF-8" Inputfile: "C" Outputdir: "C.UTF-8" failed
/bin/sh: 4: cannot create /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/localedata/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE.test-result: Directory nonexistent

ldd /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef shows the following output:
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_ABI_DT_RELR' not found (required by /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localed
ef)
/home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedd19f000)
        /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so (0x0000733af8800000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000733af8400000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000733af8ba3000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000733af8b9e000)
        /home/xray/Documents/sw/common/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000733af8c0b000)
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x0000733af8a5e000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x0000733af8a32000)
        libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x0000733af87ec000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000733af8000000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x0000733af8a2c000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x0000733af87e4000)
        libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x0000733af87cf000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000733af86e8000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000733af86c8000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x0000733af86b0000)
        libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x0000733af86a3000)

Upon setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to recent compiled glibc leads to a core dump
xray@instance-1:~/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
xray@instance-1:~/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build$ ldd /home/xray/Documents/sw/glibc-2.40_build/locale/localedef
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Ubuntu 24.10 (oracular) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the development release Ubuntu oracular and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 3 October 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 10 October 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/oracular-oriole-release-schedule/36460  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu oracular you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)   You don't specifically mention any release; but glibc6 2.40 is used only by oracular which isn't on-topic yet

@guiverc Its on Ubuntu 22.04 . I never said it was on Ubuntu 24.10 . I am talking about compiling glibc 2.40

glibc 2.40 is the version found in Ubuntu oracular, or what will be 24.10 on release; your details (as pasted) imply 24.10 as you've not said anything else.  Please amend your question.

Please note that even if you are able to compile, changing the glibc version is bound to break Ubuntu, and you will have to reinstall. Why are you trying to change glibc version?

You can have multiple glibc. I do not plan on putting it in /usr etc . I did configure --prefix=other location for it
